# javascript slideshow bug after several iterations

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I created my own picture scroll in javascript and after 3 -4 photo change my script crashes page. I do not know why! if anyone can help me?
The pictures are taken randomly from two differents files, and i stock them on an array

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="corpshaut"> 
<a href="" id="lien_banniere0" border="0" class="image-bandeau"><img src="" id="banniere0" height="150" border="0" width="150" /></a> 
<a href="" id="lien_banniere1" border="0" class="image-bandeau"><img src="" id="banniere1" height="150" border="0" width="150"/></a> 
<a href="" id="lien_banniere2" border="0" class="image-bandeau"><img src="" id="banniere2" height="150" border="0" width="150"/></a> 
<a href="" id="lien_banniere3" border="0" class="image-bandeau"><img src="" id="banniere3" height="150" border="0" width="150"/></a> 
<a href="" id="lien_banniere4" border="0" class="image-bandeau"><img src="" id="banniere4" height="150" border="0" width="150"/></a> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
boucle(); 
}); 
function boucle(){ 
/*Variablde de parametre*/ 
var nbimagetotal = 5; 
var nbimagesuivie = 1; 
var nbimagedossier = 11; 
var repertoire = 'image3/('; 
var lien = 'www.lien.fr'; 
/*-------------------------*/ 
/*Variablde*/ 
var stock = new Array(); 
var index; 
var occu; 
var nbimage = Math.floor((Math.random()*nbimagetotal)+1); 
var aleatoire; 
/*-------------------------*/ 
while (nbimagesuivie <= nbimagetotal){ 
occu=0; 
for (i=0; i<nbimage; i++){ 
aleatoire = repertoire + Math.floor((Math.random()*nbimagedossier)+1) + ').gif'; 
/*Boucle FOR permettant de verifier si l'image est déja dans le tableau*/ 
for (j =0; j<i;j++){ 
index= stock[j].indexOf(aleatoire); 
if (index != -1) { 
occu=1; 
} 
} 
if (occu==0) { 
stock[i] = new Array(); 
stock[i][0]= aleatoire; 
stock[i][1]=lien; 
nbimagesuivie = nbimagesuivie +1; 
} 
else{ 
--i; 
} 
} 
if(nbimage < 5){ 
occu=0; 
var repertoire2 = 'image2/'; 
var nbimagedossier2 = 11; 
var nbimage2 = nbimagetotal - nbimage; 
var lien2 = 'www.lien2.fr' ; 
for (i=nbimage; i<nbimagetotal; i++){ 
aleatoire = repertoire2 + Math.floor((Math.random()*nbimagedossier)+1) + '.jpg'; 
/*Boucle FOR permettant de verifier si l'image est déja dans le tableau*/ 
for (j =0; j<i;j++){ 
index= stock[j].indexOf(aleatoire); 
if (index != -1) { 
occu=1; 
} 
} 
if (occu==0) { 
stock[i] = new Array(); 
stock[i][0]= aleatoire; 
stock[i][1]=lien2; 
nbimagesuivie = nbimagesuivie +1; 
} 
else{ 
--i; 
} 
}   
} 
} 
for (i=0;i<nbimagetotal;i++){ 
$('#lien_banniere'+i).attr('href', stock[i][1]); 
$('#banniere'+i).attr('src',stock[i][0] ); 
} 
setTimeout(function(){boucle()}, 5000); 
} 
</script>
```

thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

you do have an infinite loop because if occu==1 you're doing a --i, then with the for you will do a i++ and the loop will continue this way without breaking.